# How to fix scrapy rules when only one rule is followed

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

This code is not working:

```
name="souq_com"
allowed_domains=['uae.souq.com']
start_urls=["http://uae.souq.com/ae-en/shop-all-categories/c/"]

rules = (
    #categories
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="body-column-main"]//div[contains(@class,"fl")]'),unique=True)),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="ItemResultList"]/div/div/div/a'),unique=True),callback='parse_item'),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'.*?page=\d+'),unique=True)),
)
```

The first rule is getting responses, but the second rule is not working.
I'm sure that the second's rule xpath is correct (I've tried it using scrapy shell ) I also tried adding a callback to the first rule and selecting the path of the second rule ('//div[@id="ItemResultList"]/div/div/div/a') and issuing a Request and it's working correctly.

I also tried a workaround, I tried to use a Base spider instead of a Crawl Spider, it only issues the first request and doesn't issue the callback.
how should I fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of rules is important. According to [scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules) for CrawlSpider `rules`:

> If multiple rules match the same link, the first one will be used, according to the order they’re defined in this attribute.

If I follow the first link in http://uae.souq.com/ae-en/shop-all-categories/c/, i.e. http://uae.souq.com/ae-en/antique/l/, the items you want to follow are within this structure

```
<div id="body-column-main">
    <div id="box-ads-souq-1340" class="box-container ">...
    <div id="box-results" class="box-container box-container-none ">
        <div class="box box-style-none box-padding-none">
            <div class="bord_b_dash overhidden hidden-phone">
            <div class="item-all-controls-wrapper">
            <div id="ItemResultList">
                <div class="single-item-browse fl width-175 height-310 position-relative">
                <div class="single-item-browse fl width-175 height-310 position-relative">
                ...
```

So, the links you target with the 2nd Rule are in `<div>` that have "fl" in their class, so they also match the first rule, which looks for all links in `'//div[@id="body-column-main"]//div[contains(@class,"fl")]'`, and therefore will *NOT* be parsed with `parse_item`

**Simple solution**: Try putting your 2nd rule before the "categories" Rule (`unique=True` by default for `SgmlLinkExtractor`)

```
name="souq_com"
allowed_domains=['uae.souq.com']
start_urls=["http://uae.souq.com/ae-en/shop-all-categories/c/"]

rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="ItemResultList"]/div/div/div')), callback='parse_item'),

    #categories
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="body-column-main"]//div[contains(@class,"fl")]'))),

    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'.*?page=\d+'))),
)
```

**Another option** is to change your first rule for category pages to a more restrictive XPath, that does not exist in the individual category pages, such as `'//div[@id="body-column-main"]//div[contains(@class,"fl")]//ul[@class="refinementBrowser-mainList"]'`

You could also define a regex for the category pages and use `accept` parameter in you Rules.

Comment: it worked, but do you have any idea why my rules were wrong ?

Comment: It's not that your rules were wrong. I haven't checked the details in your page but the order of rules is important if links match both rules. See [the scrapy doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules) "If multiple rules match the same link, the first one will be used, according to the order they’re defined in this attribute."

Comment: @Vanddel, I looked further and added an explanation on why the 2 rules match the same links in category pages