# Scrapy, Crawling Reviews on Tripadvisor: how to apply double recursion rules?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This is how my spider looks like:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from tripadvisor.items import TripadvisorItem,TripadvisorItem2
from tripadvisor.id_generator import id_maker
from scrapy import log

class TripadvisorSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name ="trippy5"
    allowed_domanis=["tripadvisor.com"] 
    start_urls=[
    'http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g187371-Cologne_North_Rhine_Westphalia-Hotels.html']

    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//*[@class="guiArw sprite-pageNext "]')),
            callback="parse_start_url",  follow= True),
           Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//*[@class="guiArw sprite-pageNext  pid4181"]')),
            callback="parse_hotel",  follow= True),)


    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(TripadvisorSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        self._compile_rules()
        logfile = open('tripadvisor_log.log', 'w')
        log_observer = log.ScrapyFileLogObserver(logfile, level=log.DEBUG)
        log_observer.start()
    def parse_start_url(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//div[@class="metaLocationInfo"]')
        for title in titles:
            hotel_id=id_maker()
            item = TripadvisorItem()
            item['id_hotel']=hotel_id
            item ["name"] = (title.xpath('.//a[@class="property_title"]/text()').extract()[0]).strip()
            star=title.xpath('.//img[@class="sprite-ratings-gry"]/@alt').extract()

            if star:
                star=star[0]       
            star=star[0:3]                
            item ["stars"] =star 
        else:
            item ["stars"] =999

            overall_rating=title.xpath('.//img[@class="sprite-ratings"]/@alt').extract()
            if overall_rating:
                overall_rating=overall_rating[0]
                if overall_rating[1]=='.':
                    overall_rating=overall_rating[0:3]
                else:
                    overall_rating=overall_rating[0]

                item ["overall_rating"]=overall_rating
            else:
                item ["overall_rating"]=999


            link=title.xpath('.//a[@class="property_title"]/@href').extract()[0]            
            url = "http://tripadvisor.com{}".format(link)

            yield Request(url=url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_hotel)    


    def parse_hotel(self, response):
        items=[]
        item = response.meta['item']
        sel = Selector(response)

        review_boxes =sel.xpath('//*[@class="reviewSelector "]')        
        if review_boxes:            
            for box in review_boxes:
                if box.xpath('.//span[@class="noQuotes"]/text()').extract():
                    item2=TripadvisorItem2()
                    item2 ['id_hotel']=item['id_hotel']
                    item2 ["hotel_name"]=item ["name"]
                    item2 ["review_title"] = box.xpath('.//span[@class="noQuotes"]/text()').extract()[0]
                    item2 ["review_rate"] =box.xpath('.//div/div/span/img/@alt').extract()[0][0]                  
                    if box.xpath('.//div/div/span/@title').extract():                    
                        item2 ["review_date"] =box.xpath('.//div/div/span/@title').extract()[0]                    
                    else:                        
                        item2 ["review_date"] =(box.xpath('.//div/div/span[@class="ratingDate"]/text()').extract()[0]).replace('Reviewed ','')                  
                    contributor_name=box.xpath('.//div[@class="username mo"]/span/text()').extract()
                    if contributor_name:
                        item2 ["contributor_name"] =contributor_name[0]
                    location=box.xpath('.//div[@class="location"]/text()').extract()                   
                    if location:
                        if location==[u'\n']:
                            item2 ["contributor_location"]='N/A' 
                        else:
                            item2 ["contributor_location"]=(location[0]).strip()
                    overall_contributions=box.xpath('.//span[@class="badgeText"]/text()').extract()
                    if overall_contributions:
                        item2 ["overall_contributions"] =((overall_contributions[0]).replace(' review','')).replace('s','')
                    else:
                        item2 ["overall_contributions"] =999
                    item2 ["text"] =(box.xpath('.//div[@class="entry"]/p/text()').extract())[0].strip()
                    items.append(item2)

                    yield item2
```

the first rule works successfully, crawling through all the pages listing the hotels.

the spider crawls only through the first page of each hotel's reviews and unfortunately ignores the second rule that should let it crawl recursevely through al reviews' pages.

I don't think that [How to fix scrapy rules when only one rule is followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427712/how-to-fix-scrapy-rules-when-only-one-rule-is-followed) applies here because of the differente callbacks and different xpaths.

I beg for help!